# Simplifying the statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Can anyone please help or suggest to simplify the following condition:

```
if (null == parentInstruction.getQuantity() || 
       (null != parentInstruction.getQuantity() && 
           (
           (parentInstruction.getQuantity().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 && !canSkipTransTypeCds(parentInstruction)) || 
           (parentInstruction.getQuantity().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0)
           )
       )
   )  {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: What does this condition do?

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm usually a fan of single if-statements, if the code becomes unreadable it's best to split it up.

```
if(parentInstruction.getQuantity() == null)
  return true;
if(parentInstruction.getQuantity().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0)
  return true;
if(!canSkipTransTypeCds(parentInstruction))
  return true;
```

After the first if-statement `parentInstruction.getQuantity()` can never<sup>*†*</sup> be `null`, otherwise it would have already returned, so no need to check `!= null`.

After the second if-statement `parentInstruction.getQuantity()` will always<sup>*†*</sup> be `0` , otherwise it would have already returned, so no need to check `== 0`.

<sup>*†: Unless calling `.getQuantity()` changes the value at the same time of course, but since it's a getter let's assume it never changes the return-value..*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a one-liner, it comes down to:

```html
if (!BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(parentInstruction.getQuantity()) || !canSkipTransTypeCds(parentInstruction)) 
  return true;
```

Personally I suggest Kevin's approach tho.

Comment: I thought about adding how `.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0` could be simplified to `.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)` as well, but didn't really thought it was necessary. But using `BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(...)` to prevent the potential NPE is smart; making the code a lot simpler and still a single check, so +1 from me.